# Jenkins pipeline and Robot Framework results

Tags: jenkins, robotframework, jenkins-pipeline

I had to implement a Pipeline and trying to find a way, how to publish Robot Framework results in Jenkins Pipeline. 
I found [multiple questions](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Robot+Framework+Plugin?focusedCommentId=105152520#comment-105152520) about implementation of Robot Framework plugin into Pipeline and also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42210598/publish-multiple-robot-test-results-from-jenkins-pipeline) which seems to be solution. However I have tried this approach and results are still missing.

Is there any workaround or functional example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Edited to reflect successful workaround]

[This comment on the issue tracker shows a workaround that seems to work](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34469?focusedCommentId=293103&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-293103):

```
step([
    $class : 'RobotPublisher',
    outputPath : outputDirectory,
    outputFileName : "*.xml",
    disableArchiveOutput : false,
    passThreshold : 100,
    unstableThreshold: 95.0,
    otherFiles : "*.png",
])
```

However, the Robot Framework Plugin currently does not seem to be fully compatible with Pipeline right now: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34469

This is common with [many plugins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md) in the Jenkins ecosystem right now that have not been updated yet to be compatible with the new Jenkins Pipeline. [You could potentially create the full compatibility yourself though](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/DEVGUIDE.md), if you're motivated enough.

Comment: Thank you, I actually have not realised, that [this workaround works](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34469?focusedCommentId=293103&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-293103).

Comment: I added to pipeline just this step:

`step([$class: 'RobotPublisher',
disableArchiveOutput: false,
logFileName: 'log.html',
otherFiles: '',
outputFileName: 'output.xml',
outputPath: 'report/',
passThreshold: 100,
reportFileName: 'report.html',
unstableThreshold: 0]);`

**I have found "Robot Test Summary" in detail of each build with path to log.html and report.html, which is quite enough for me.** There is also a button to "Robot Results" with a graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I used the workaround mentioned in the other answer but it wouldn't display the results with the job like in non pipline jobs, so i made freestyle project that is triggered by the pipline job and just copies the results files across then runs the analysis. This is crufty and won't be portable across nodes, the job numbers might get confusing over time so the correlations might be tricky. At the point i will investigate using generic artifact storage or just getting rid of robot altogether.

Comment: i used this groovy snippet to reset the build numbers of each job to match, just enter it in the script console (http://yourjenkins/script) and change myjob to your job name and run this for each job  to sync

item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("MYJOB)
//THIS WILL REMOVE ALL BUILD HISTORY
item.builds.each() { build ->
  build.delete()
}
item.updateNextBuildNumber(1)

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble using the answer given above, resulting in errors; but I was able to figure it out and add it to the Pipeline. Here is how I fixed it in case anyone else has come across the same issues:

```
stage('Tests') {

  steps {
    echo 'Testing...'
    script {
      step(
        [
          $class                    : 'RobotPublisher',
          outputPath                : '<insert/the/output/path>',
          outputFileName            : "*.xml",
          reportFileName            : "report.html",
          logFileName               : "log.html",
          disableArchiveOutput      : false,
          passThreshold             : 100,
          unstableThreshold         : 95.0,
          otherFiles                : "*.png"
        ]
      )
    }  
  }
}
```